# One query to calculate distance without nested query

Tags: sql, greatest-n-per-group

Is it possible to write query without any nested queries to for each city from column1 find the closest on from column2 and display City1, City2 and distance

```
    Table:
City1, City2, Distance
```

for example

```
City1, city2, Distance
A B 10
A C 20
A D 30
E F 40
E G 10

re result should be:

A B 10
E G 40
```

Thanks for any help

Comment: Shouldn't your last result record be "E G 10"?

Comment: Please could you advise as to why you need to avoid nested queries?  Depending on the logic required, nested queries can be both the tidiest and fastest solutions available.  (Nested queries are not  universally bad idea by any means at all.)  Also, what version of SQL are you using?

Answer (score 4):

This is a variation on the `greatest-n-per-group` query.  This type of query has come up frequently on Stack Overflow.

```
SELECT c1.City1, c1.City2, c1.Distance
FROM Cities AS c1
LEFT OUTER JOIN Cities AS c2
  ON c1.City1 = c2.City1 AND c1.Distance > c2.Distance
WHERE c2.City1 IS NULL;
```

In other words, find the city pair from row `c1` such that no other city pair `c2` exists with the same City1 and a closer City2.

Comment: While your answer, as asked, does not strictly involve nested queries, I must say I find the version with a nested query inside a NOT EXISTS *much* clearer.

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to ROW_NUMBER() and Common Table Expressions (such as in Oracle10g and SQL Server 2005, etc)...

```
WITH
  ordered_results AS
(
  SELECT
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY City1 ORDER BY Distance, City2) AS rank,
    City1,
    City2,
    Distance
  FROM
    Cities
)
SELECT
  City1,
  City2,
  Distance
FROM
  ordered_results
WHERE
  rank = 1
```

Depending on what you mean by "nested queries", this may or may not be acceptable to you.

But in any reasonably sized data-set I've been almost guaranteed to find this the most generically effective solution.

Answer (score 0):

This is not the best, but will

SELECT LEAST (city1, city2) city1,
         GREATEST (city1, city2) city2,
         distance
    FROM distance
GROUP BY LEAST (city1,city2), GREATEST (city1,city2), distance